# getInitialProps inside _app.js breaks 404-page

Tags: next.js, jsx

I want to fetch data from a cms for a nav-bar that are used on all pages.

For that i'm using getInitialProps inside _app.js, in order to not repeat myself.

However if I visit a path that doesn't exist I get a page with this error instead of the default 404-page,
"Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)."
(console says 404 btw)

This is my code:

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, navData }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout navData={navData}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
  // if (ctx.res.statusCode !== 200) {
  //   ctx.res.writeHead(ctx.res.statusCode, { Location: "/" });
  //   ctx.res.end();
  //   return;
  // }

  const json = await FetchGQL(NavQuery);
  return { navData: json.data.allPosts };
};
```

I've tried to handle the redirect manually (commented out), which works in dev, but throws an error when i build

Does someone have an idea how to solve this?

Thanks :D

Comment: I don't think NextJS since version 12 allow to use `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps` in `_app.js` anymore. Best would be to call it on all pages components, but factorize it with a Higher Order Component (HOC) and call it in `getServerSideProps` with await. This way, default 404 would not use it when you reach a not found error.